# How to accept value on option box

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I had a list array of ng-model on my options. Each ng-model assign with different values depends on the user inputs. It works for me when I tried to select the options box and the result produced what I want. But when I retrieved new data from API and parse the value into that options box. Is not working.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-repeat="($a_choice_index, c) in menu.additionalchoice">
  <label for="max_select" class="rl-label required">Do you want maximum select?
    <label for="max_select" class="select-block">
      <select id="max_select" name="max_select" ng-model="c[$a_choice_index].maxSelect" ng-change="selectMaxSelect(c[$a_choice_index].maxSelect, $a_choice_index)" ng-options="o.name for o in maxSelectOptions"></select>
      <svg class="svg-arrow">
        <use xlink:href="#svg-arrow"></use>
      </svg>
    </label>
  </label>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.menu = {};
$scope.maxSelectOptions = [
 {
    name: "No",
    value: 0
 }, 
 {
    name: "Yes",
    value: 1
 }
];

$scope.selectMaxSelect = function(v, index){
  $scope.menu.mealchoices[index].max_select = v;
};

MyService.GetData(function(menu){
    $scope.menu = menu; // menu.additionalchoice is added into menu
});
```

**API Data**

Each menu.additionalchoice produces

> {"1":{"title":"Add favorite oils","maxSelect":{"name":"No","value":0}},"title":"Add favorite oils","max_select":4,"additional_choice":1,"maxSelect":1,"meals":...

When I tried to:

1) `ng-init="c[$a_choice_index].maxSelect = c.maxSelect"`

It shows empty.

2) `ng-init="selectMaxSelect(c.maxSelect, $a_choice_index)"`

It shows some values but the value is incorrect. `c[$a_choice_index].maxSelect` returns `{"name": "No", "value": 0}` when the `c.maxSelect == 1` which is YES.

Comment: Can You Create Plukr .

Comment: Try ng-init="c[$a_choice_index].maxSelect=o[0]"

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the select option by value only by using `... as ... for ... in ...` syntax, which is a lot easier compare to binding using object.

`ng-options="o.value as o.name for o in maxSelectOptions"`

The result in `ng-model` should now be 0 or 1 instead of an object.